# Adding jpg extension in javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have an image that I am trying to create as an attachment. I need to send the attachment as a jpg attachment. While I am able to send the attachment successfully, the file does not have the jpg extension. I am not clear how to add it.

```
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(text);
Multipart multipart = new javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
**DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(image, "application/x-any");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));**
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the correct mime type: `image/jpg`. 
Furthermore, add the filename to your source: `source.setFileName("myimage.jpg");`